# Change the value format of the date in ProTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I would like to change the value format of the date in Ant Design ProTable. Instead of the default `date` valueType (YYYY-MM-DD) I would like to use `{moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}`. If I use the `render` prop for this column, valueType is set to string, and in Search, there is no DatePicker, just a regular input.

Here is how the column looks like with `render` prop:

```
{
  title: 'Date',
  dataIndex: 'createdAt',
  render: (dom) => {
    return <span>{moment(dom).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}</span>;
  }
}
```

Here is a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-rgb-ecohv?file=/App.tsx). If you remove render from date column and uncomment valueType, then there is a DatePicker in search above the table. I need the same behavior but with formatted moment date. How can I do that?

Comment: In the span, do you want a `string` or a `JS date` or a `moment date`?

Comment: I guess I want a formatted moment date to be displayed in a column. But the column itself needs to be of valueType `date`, so that I can use DatePicker on it in search.

Comment: See this: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-leakey-igmpt?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Magofoco I've added a codesandbox